# Monogame VsCode extension isn't working properly when I try to use it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, monogame

I tried to use The VsCode extension `monogame-pipeline-vscode`, but it doesnt work. There is no documentation, and I cant figure it out. I can install it fine, but when I right click the mgcb file I want to open, then click "Open In Pipeline", It doesnt work. Is there  something I need to install first?

Here is the id thing for the extension:

`abcdef.monogame-pipeline-vscode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure you have installed the Monogame Pipeline. You can install the `mgcb-editor` tool with the following script:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-mgcb-editor
mgcb-editor --register
```

Next, edit the setting in VS Code's `setting.json` as

```json
"mgcb.pipelineToolPath": "mgcb-editor"
```

Needless to say, this will invoke the `mgcb-editor` command along with the file path of the `*.mgcb` file as parameter. If you have the older version of the pipeline tool installed elsewhere, you'll need to enter the path accordingly.

Comment: I have also submitted a PR to the repository for including these instructions and changing the default setting